# Click handler in Apple Script

Tags: applescript, bash

I created a standalone macOS app using Script Editor. Upon starting, the app executes a bash script and upon quitting, the app executes another bash script. The code looks like this

```
do shell script "complete path to start script"
on quit 
     do shell script "complete path to quit script"
     continue quit
end quit
```

When I open the app it does what it is supposed to do and the app resides in the dock until it is closed. I would like the finder to open a specific folder when I click on the app symbol in the dock. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: By specifically clicking on the dock icon is rather difficult to implement.  However, since clicking on the dock icon would also activate or bring your app into focus, this is something that can be implemented relatively simply.

Comment: I'm glad it's simple. Any hints on how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Getting your application to respond specifically to a user clicking on its dock icon is difficult.  A simpler task is to get your application to respond to acquiring focus where it previously belonged to another application, i.e. whenever your application is brought into the foreground, which clicking on the dock icon will do.

I've heavily commented the script below to walk you through what's relevant.  Anything I've left uncommented or haven't specifically made reference to in the comments should be left alone and where it is, unless you're confident you know what you're doing.

Obviously, this won't do a lot if it's simply run from within *Script Editor*, so incorporate this into your application's AppleScript code (or, rather, incorporate your application's AppleScript code into this), save it, and run the applet.  If you don't make any edits to it whatsoever, then when saved as an applet, you'll see a notification appear every 10 seconds telling you the application is *"idling..."*; and a dialog box will pop-up whenever the application is brought into focus informing you that it *"Acquired focus."*.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------|
on run
    _init()

    # Your startup code goes here, which will
    # execute once when your application runs
    # e.g.
    #   do shell script "/path/to/start-script.sh"
end run

on idle
    # Any code you need to run repeatedly can
    # go here.  Otherwise, you can delete this
    # entire handler

    # The following line is test code:
    display notification "idling..."

    # The return value is how often (in seconds)
    # this handler will be called
    return 10
end idle

on activate
    # Insert code you want to execute whenever
    # your application receives focus, e.g.
    # 
    #   tell application "System Events" to ¬
    #       open folder "~/Path/To/Folder/"

    # The following line is test code:
    display dialog "Focus acquired."
end activate

on quit
    global |@|
    |@|'s removeObserver:me

    # Any other clean-up code that needs to
    # execute just before your application
    # exits should go here, e.g.
    #   do shell script "/path/to/quit-script.sh"

    continue quit
end quit
-----------------------------------------------------------|
# PRIVATE HANDLERS:
use framework "Foundation"
use framework "AppKit"
use scripting additions

property |@| : a reference to my NSWorkspace's ¬
    sharedWorkspace's notificationCenter

on _init()
    "NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification"
    |@|'s addObserver:me selector:("_notify:") ¬
        |name|:result object:(missing value)

    idle
end _init

to _notify:notification
    local notification
    if my id = the notification's userInfo()'s ¬
        NSWorkspaceApplicationKey's ¬
        bundleIdentifier() as text ¬
        then activate me
end _notify:
-----------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: Many thanks @CJK ! So I used `do shell script "open path to folder"` instead to open the folder, as the proposed code somehow does not seem to work on my system. What does not work as I had hoped is that if I activate the application, either by clicking the dock icon or by using command tab, then I do not get a menu for the application in the menu bar. So if I want to quit the application, then I have to right click on the dock icon and select quit. I'd be nice to be able to use command q for this.

Comment: Re: System Events: can you paste the **exact** line of code you used to try and open the folder with _System Events_.  When you say it didn't work, did anything at all happen ? Re: menu: when I run the applet, I **do** get a menu in the menu bar, and `cmd`+`Q` works. Does your applet have a menu when you first open the applet, and has it therefore somehow disappeared ? Or is there no menu to begin with, in which case that's a setting you've applied yourself somewhere along the line. Let me know the details for these two problems and I'll help you fix it when I'm back on tomorrow.

Comment: I copied your code into the Script Editor. Then I uncommented the line `tell application "System Events" to ¬` and the one after it. I replaced `"~/Path/To/Folder"`with an actual folder. For instance `"~/Music/"`. Then I saved the code as an app and selected "Stay open after run handler". This does not work, i.e., the folder is not opened in the Finder, also when replacing the relative path with an absolute path. Occasionally the applet even crashes.

Comment: Did the dialog display ?  Other than putting in the System Events call, was anything else about the script changed from what it currently looks like here ?  When it crashes, what action were you performing immediately prior to the crash ?  Was there an error message to go with it ?  If not, Console will have a log of the crash, but don't worry for now.  I'll run the applet for all of today and see if it crashes on me.

Comment: The script without modification does exactly what it is supposed to do. First show the "idling" notification and upon activation it shows the dialog box "Focus acquired." If I change the two lines -- and only those two lines -- as stated above, the "idling" notification still appears, but upon activation I get the spinning beach ball and bit later the applet goes into "not responding" state. BTW -- I very much appreciate your help with this. Thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome, it's always nice to help someone that engages and appreciates it.  So I _believe_ I've figured out the reasons behind each of the issues, including the missing menu you experienced. I'll write an addendum to my answer to explain what is going on with _System Events_, and also what to keep in mind (which stupidly didn't occur to me before now) when you write code to put inside the `on activate` handler: if it performs any action that results in another application's activation, then it can never keep focus itself as it always passes it to the other app. Hence...no menu.

Comment: I'm just doing a re-write of it now to see what the best approach is for that.